# RXTX not working in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, rxtx

Finally managed to read from rxtx in windows but now I just cannot make it work in Ubuntu.I get the rxtx libs using apt-get ,but when i run the application,i can not see anything,tried a couple of try-catch blocks and i don't even get the exceptions,and since Ubuntu based debugging is not possible for now, i can not pinpoint the problem.
(Ubuntu is 12.04 64 bit).

```
import gnu.io.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ReadComPort {

    public static void main(String[] s) {
        readcomport();
    }

    public static String readcomport() {
        String value = null;

        try {
            // CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier
            // .getPortIdentifier("COM1");

            // String comportidentifier = "COM1"; //*win
            String comportidentifier = "/dev/ttyS0";

            CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = null;
            portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(comportidentifier);

            if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "port in use");
            } else {

                SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) portIdentifier.open("ReadComPort", 500);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, serialPort.getBaudRate());

                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(serialPort.getBaudRate(), SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                // serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN | SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);
                serialPort.setDTR(true);
                serialPort.setRTS(true);

                InputStream mInputFromPort = serialPort.getInputStream();

                Thread.sleep(500);
                byte mBytesIn[] = new byte[32];
                mInputFromPort.read(mBytesIn);

                value = new String(mBytesIn);

                mInputFromPort.close();
                serialPort.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception : " + ex.getMessage());

        }

        return value;

    }
}
```

Comment: Did u add rxtx library in classpath. I find u have not imported the appropriate class in ur java file.

Comment: RXTXcomm.jar file is added to the build path...

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the configuration file `javax.comm.properties` is on the classpath.  I have had endless issues with RXTX because of this file - it just fails silently.

Comment: erm cant seem to find it...Where is it located normally?

Comment: ah.  That's likely the issue then.  Check here : http://pradnyanaik.wordpress.com/2009/04/07/communicating-with-ports-using-javaxcomm-package-for-windows/ - you will probably need to find a javax-comm package somewhere that contains the properties file

Comment: OK found a rar file which contains 3 files,and one of them is the .properties file.How do i add it? From build path/configure build path menu?

Comment: Add it as a project resource, I presume.

Comment: Tried adding it to resources and to my usr/jdk/... folders and stil nothing,meh :/

Comment: Now i'm getting gnu.io.nosuchportexception error.At least it shows some signs of life :)

Comment: hah. yes, that's a bit healthier.  Now you probably just need to make sure the serial ports are accessible to the user your process is running as :)

Comment: "Caught java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.nativeGetVersion()Ljava/lang/String; while loading driver gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver"   grrrrrrrrrr,seriously does anybody here got this rxtx thingie to work?

Comment: Have you succeeded in your problem? I've been working on the same problem almost a week.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday, and found [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=6011):

```
String serialPortID = "/dev/ttyAMA0";
System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", serialPortID);
```

Thath is, you need to set the `gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts` system property, and the value should be the name of the port you want to open.

Comment: Could you please indicate how to set `gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts` system property?

Comment: That's what I'm doing in the code: `System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", serialPortID);`